# Methods not generated for Opinions with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, redis, mongoid

I'm trying to build an application on RoR that uses MongoDB via Mongoid for the main objects but has a like and dislike process using Redis via Opinions https://github.com/leehambley/opinions/.

It sort of works but when I run the methods on my objects I just get an error "undefined method `like_by'" where I think the methods are supposed to be autogenerated.

My model looks like:

```
class Punchline
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Opinions::Pollable

  opinions :like, :dislike

  field :key, type: String
  field :text, type: String
  field :won, type: Boolean
  field :created, type: Time, default: ->{ Time.now }
  field :score, type: Integer

  index({ key: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "key_index" })
  belongs_to :user
  embedded_in :joke
end
```

and I run:

```
user = User.find(session[:userid])
@joke.punchlines.sample.like_by(user);
```

But it fails with the undefined method error :(

Do I need to initialize Opinions somewhere beyond

/config/initializers/opinions.rb

```
Opinions.backend       = Opinions::RedisBackend.new
Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that Opinions doesn't really work. Why is a bit beyond my two weeks with Rails :)

Anyway, it turns out that this is really easy to do by hand anyway especially as I only had a like and dislike to handle.

I used a Redis sorted set which allows a unique key - value pair with a score. I used a score of +1 or -1 to denote like or dislike and then encoded the key to represent the liked object and the value to be the user id.

This looked like:

```
def like(user)
    $redis.zadd('joke:'+self.key+':likes', 1, user._id)
end

def dislike(user)
    $redis.zadd('joke:'+self.key+':likes', -1, user._id)
end

def numLikes
    res = $redis.zrangebyscore('joke:'+self.key+':likes',1,1);
    return res.count
end

def numDislikes
    res = $redis.zrangebyscore('joke:'+self.key+':likes',-1,-1);
    return res.count
end

def likedBy(user)

    res = $redis.zscore('joke:'+self.key+':likes',user._id)

    return (res == 1)

end

def dislikedBy(user)
    res = $redis.zscore('joke:'+self.key+':likes',user._id)

    return (res == -1)

end
```